# An alternate way to display images on an android app

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have my `ImageView` laid out in an `.xml` file and in my main java file I am using the code

`static int[] images = { R.drawable.green_0, R.drawable.blue_1,
            R.drawable.purple_2, R.drawable.pink_3, R.drawable.red_4,
            R.drawable.yellow_5, R.drawable.white_6, R.drawable.teal_7,
            R.drawable.babyblue_8, R.drawable.lightgreen_9,
            R.drawable.magenta_10, R.drawable.grey_12, R.drawable.black_11 };`

to display images. However, later in the code I am trying to use the line

`holder.image.setImageBitmap(images[position].getImage());`

which gives the error

> "Cannot invoke getImage() on the primitive type int"

How else can I display images in my app to use that line of code with no errors (not declaring the images as boolean type int).

Comment: Try removing getImage method call from images[position], it should be like this:

Comment: you can use `holder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);`

Comment: @Daniel - that won't work. You have to use setImageResource if you are setting it to a resource Id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are working with integer values.
You need to transform this int in Drawable, or Bitmap like this:

```
holder.image.setImageResource(images[position])
```

or

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( images[position] ));
```

or

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  images[position]));
```

Comment: holder.image.setImageResource(images[position]) makes more sense for your 2nd statement

Comment: That got rid of the error, now I'm getting a fatal exception: main. One problem gone another comes to replace it.

Comment: I'm new here how do I post a log from eclipse?

Comment: Open logcat (http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) and copy paste the problem (message in red) in a new question.

Comment: 10-15 15:59:59.080: E/AndroidRuntime(3241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-15 15:59:59.080: E/AndroidRuntime(3241): java.lang.NullPointerException 10-15 15:59:59.080: E/AndroidRuntime(3241): at com.practice.imagegrid.tabs.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:67)

Comment: ImageAdapter.java:67 is the line of code I just added holder.image.setImageResource(images[position])

Comment: Make sure your view holder isn't empty and that the imageView exists within the view holder.

Comment: Just before this line you can add something like Log.i("Debug",""+holder.image); to check that's a null value, and then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`setImageBitmap()` takes in a Bitmap object, not an int.  The int you are supplying is just the id in the R.java generated resources file.

Use [BitmapFactory.decodeResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29):

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), images[position]));
```

Comment: @InsertName, I'm not sure why you posted those comments...  My answer doesn't involve setImageResource.